# Cannot print to Boomaga virtual printer from Google Chrome

Tags: printing, google-chrome, 21.10, virtual-printer

I have been using **Boomaga** "virtual printer for CUPS" version 3.0.0. When I try to print form **Google Chrome** (version 95.0.4638.54) to this printer, nothing happens. I see these messages in *syslog*:

```
[5005:5005:1028/182335.523604:ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(214)] SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to Produce a Skia representation from a non-existent mailbox.
[5005:5005:1028/182335.524104:ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(214)] SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to Produce a Skia representation from a non-existent mailbox.
[5005:5005:1028/182335.524513:ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(214)] SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to Produce a Skia representation from a non-existent mailbox.
[5005:5005:1028/182335.524990:ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(214)] SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to Produce a Skia representation from a non-existent mailbox.
[5005:5005:1028/182335.525391:ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(214)] SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to Produce a Skia representation from a non-existent mailbox.
[5005:5005:1028/182335.525867:ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(214)] SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to Produce a Skia representation from a non-existent mailbox.
[5005:5005:1028/182335.526349:ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(214)] SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to Produce a Skia representation from a non-existent mailbox.
[5005:5005:1028/182335.526766:ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(214)] SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to Produce a Skia representation from a non-existent mailbox.
```

There is not any problem in printing to **Boomaga** from **gedit**, **LibreOffice**, **geany**, etc.

(Although [some programs have another similar problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1372313), I think this is another problem that started after upgrading from 21.04 to 21.10.)

**Notes:**

- Other printers work fine.
- Chrome prints OK when I choose to *Print using system dialog...* under *More settings*.

Comment: Can't reproduce with Chrome @ *Version 95.0.4638.69 (Official Build) (64-bit)* on fully updated Ubuntu 21.10.

Comment: @N0rbert : I can't reproduce this problem in another 21.10 installation (virtual machine). My problem is on my primary notebook (physical machine). I will try to find out the differences between these two systems and update my question.