# "I can't start gs converter..." error while printing to Boomaga in Ubuntu 21.10 from Lazarus

Tags: printing, 21.10, lazarus, virtual-printer

On the previous versions of Ubuntu (21.04 and below) I didn't have this problem. This problem started after upgrade to 21.10.

[**Lazarus**](https://www.lazarus-ide.org/) version 2.0.12 64-linux-gtk2 is getting the following error while printing to virtual printer **Boomaga** version 3.0.0 on Ubuntu 21.10:

> I can't start gs converter: "GPL Ghostscript 9.54.0: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
> "

Actually, this message is displayed by Boomaga itself. However, other applications on Ubuntu 21.10 (like **gedit**, **geany**, **LibreOffice**, etc.) do not have this problem and print OK.

Please, note that this problem does not occur in Lazarus while printing on other printers (like **Generic CUPS-PDF Printer** for example).

Applications developed by Lazarus have the same problem too.

Since the version of Boomaga is the same on both Ubuntu 21.04 and 21.10, I compared the versions of the GhostScipt command: Version of **gs** is 9.53.3 on Ubuntu 21.04, while it is 9.54.0 on Ubuntu 21.10.

What may have changed in gs between versions 9.53 and 9.54 that generates this error?

Comment: See to be a bug, reported it as https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lazarus/+bug/1949192 .

Comment: Thanks @N0rbert. I think it is a Boomaga incompatibility with the next version of gs.